# why does my phython dice keep repeating the same roll?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm really new to programming and my professor wants us to write a dice game. At first, it was working correctly now it keeps repeating the same answer every roll. Please help!

```
import random

turns = 0


dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
total = dice1 + dice2


while turns < 4:
    turns = turns + 1
    print("Presss enter to roll.")
    input()
    print("You rolled a {} and a {} ".format(dice1, dice2) + \
    "for a total of {}.".format(total))

    if total==7:
        print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")


    elif total==11:
        print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")

    elif dice1==dice2:
        print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")
```

Comment: How many rolls are being performed inside that loop?

Comment: Its because you have the `dice1` and `dice2` value outside the loop. For each iteration, the `dice1` and `dice2` would be same. Move those initialization inside the `while` loop.

Comment: What in the world is a Phython dice? Sounds pretty rare. Perhaps it was designed to always produce the same outcome each time it was rolled.

Answer (score 2):

You are not re-rolling dice move the `random.randint` in while loop

```
import random

turns = 0

while turns < 4:
    dice1 = random.randint(1, 6) // dice1 & dice2 should be assigned every iteration
    dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    total = dice1 + dice2
    turns = turns + 1
    print("Presss enter to roll.")
    input()
    print("You rolled a {} and a {} ".format(dice1, dice2) + \
    "for a total of {}.".format(total))

    if total==7:
        print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")

    elif total==11:
        print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")

    elif dice1==dice2:
        print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define the dice on each iteration of the loop.  As it is currently, the dice are defined once and then reused on each iteration. Your "press enter" input is a little funky as well. You can just put the message in the input method. Here's a working example:

```
import random

turns = 0

while turns < 4:
  dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
  dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
  total = dice1 + dice2
  turns = turns + 1
  input("Press enter to continue.")
  print("You rolled a {} and a {} ".format(dice1, dice2) + \
  "for a total of {}.".format(total))

  if total==7:
      print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")

  elif total==11:
      print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")

  elif dice1==dice2:
      print("Congratulations! You are a winner!!!")
```